# Time Machine and an Unmounted Internal Drive

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, backup, hard-drive, ssd

A couple of weeks back I put an SSD in my macbook, keeping the old spinning disk drive around using an expansion bay. Everything went fine, and I got it backing up. However, having the SSD around, I decided to save some power on my last flight and unmount my spinning disk.

I totally forgot until today, when I needed to mount the drive again (because it's where my iTunes library resides). No biggie... except that it seems that Time Machine deleted all the backups of the spinning disk hard drive while it was disconnected!

Now that Time Machine sees the drive again, it's backing up the whole thing again. Looking inside the BackupDB, it's cleaned all my backups older than today (because the space was needed for today's massive re-backup), and so all of a sudden I have no backup of that spinning disk [1].

Can I *change* this behaviour? Or **must** I have the spinning disk mounted every time TM backs up?

---

[1]  Well, I have an online backup, but to me, that's last-last-resort.

Comment: If not mounted it won't backup and it will forget about it because you unmounted it. Why are you unmounting an internal disk anyway?

Comment: This spinning disk is a power hog, especially when travelling.